# Trait can't be made Object Safe when Hash + PartialEq are Supertraits

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I'm pretty new to Rust, so there is the possibility that this will be an easy Question.

I'm trying to create a small registry for Handlers that should return any struct that implements the `TransferObject` Trait:

```rust
pub trait TransferObject: Hash + PartialEq {}
```

Since I store the Handlers that are registered in a `HashMap` the Trait needs the `Hash` and `PartialEq` as the Supertraits:

```rust
pub struct RequestHandlerRegistry {
    handlers: HashMap<RequestMethod, HashMap<String, RequestHandler<dyn TransferObject>>>,
}
```

But in the Struct I get the Error, that `TransferObject` can't be made into an Object since `PartialEq` uses the parameter `Self`.
I already tried to do something like this:

```rust
pub struct RequestHandlerRegistry {
    handlers: HashMap<RequestMethod, HashMap<String, RequestHandler<Box<dyn TransferObject>>>>,
}
```

But I still get the same Error.
Is there some way to get around this?
I also created a [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b0e2a41dcce9cb4a4de5c0678cfdc2f) for easy recreation of the Error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't work because `PartialEq` by default means `PartialEq<Self>`.  When using dynamic dispatch (`dyn`) there isn't enough information to know what `Self` is and therefore what type of reference the methods of `PartialEq` can accept.

However, your question belies a misunderstanding that got you into this mess:

> Since I store the Handlers that are registered in a `HashMap` the Trait needs the `Hash` and `PartialEq` as the Supertraits

**This is only true for things you use as *keys*.** There are no such restrictions on *values*.

You can therefore drop the supertraits `Hash` and `PartialEq` from this trait; instead you need to add `Hash`, `PartialEq`, and `Eq` to the `#[derive]` macro for `RequestMethod`, since that's what you're using as a key.

Finally, you will indeed need `Box` to hold the `dyn TransferObject` values to give them a known size.