# How do I approach this trait object problem?

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I have code similar to the one below ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5fa215548fa05194a5ea6b821227da70)):

```rs
trait SomeTrait {
    fn some_fn(&self) -> i32;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz(Box<dyn SomeTrait>),
}

fn main() {
    // Do something with Foo
}
```

I have a trait object being held in `Foo::Baz` and I want whatever to be in there to have `Debug`, `Clone`, and `Eq` derived. The above code won't compile and you'll get an error saying that the trait object doesn't implement the derived traits. I get *why* it doesn't compile. But I want to know how I can solve this problem. In my actual project, all the derived traits are necessary so simply removing them isn't an option. I thought about using super traits but when you try to write something like:

```rs
trait SomeTrait: DynClone + std::fmt::Debug + Eq + PartialEq {
    fn some_fn(&self) -> i32;
}
```

This would require the struct that `SomeTrait` is being implemented for to have already derived all of the required traits so that it can be used in `Foo`. Unfortunately now I get an error saying that the trait cannot be made into an object, and I don't understand what it means by that. Can anybody help me figure out how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The error means that not every trait can be made into a trait object. Here is more detailed [explanation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0255-object-safety.md). You can not use Self in generic parameters of such traits while all Clone, Eq and PartialEq do use Self. When using `dyn` (dynamic dispatch) there isn't enough information to know what Self is and therefore what type of reference the methods of Clone, Eq or PartialEq can accept(explained [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/compiler/rustc_error_codes/src/error_codes/E0038.md) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717646/trait-cant-be-made-object-safe-when-hash-partialeq-are-supertraits)).

Why don't you go with static dispatch instead of dynamic dispath? Then everything works and you have improved performance at runtime

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait SomeTrait{

    fn some_fn(&self) -> i32;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Foo<T:SomeTrait> {
    Bar,
    Baz(T),
}

fn main() {
    // Do something with Foo
}
```

Comment: Documentation on this error https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/compiler/rustc_error_codes/src/error_codes/E0038.md also explains it well. `Clone`, `Eq` and `PartialEq` all fall into the second case that violates object safety.