# Java like interfaces in object oriented code in Rust using traits in Hashset

Tags: rust

I am struggling to make this work:

```rust
trait HasVoice: PartialEq + Eq + Hash {
    fn talk(self: &Self) {}
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Hash, Eq)]
struct Duck {
    name: String,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Hash, Eq)]
struct Dog {
    breed: String,
}

impl HasVoice for Duck {
    fn talk(self: &Self) {
        println!("duck quack!")
    }
}

impl HasVoice for Dog {
    fn talk(self: &Self) {
        println!("dog bark!")
    }
}

fn test() {
    let duck: Duck = Duck {
        name: "duckie".to_string(),
    };

    let dog: Dog = Dog {
        breed: "labrador".to_string(),
    };

    let mut quack_set: HashSet<Box<dyn HasVoice>> = HashSet::new();

    quack_set.insert(duck);
    quack_set.insert(dog);
}
```

I am getting:

```
the trait `HasVoice` cannot be made into an object
`HasVoice` cannot be made into an objectrustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
main.rs(59, 17): for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
```

Comment: Nit: Why use this explicit syntax `self: &Self` instead of just `&self`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trait can't be made Object Safe when Hash + PartialEq are Supertraits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717646/trait-cant-be-made-object-safe-when-hash-partialeq-are-supertraits)

Comment: In Rust you'll often see this done through composition, like `pub enum Voiced { Dog(Dog), Duck(Duck) }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: You didn't specify how to compare `Dog`s and `Duck`s, so the compiler is complaining at you. You have to provide a way for them to be compared.**

The solution to this is way more complicated than I was expecting, and probably isn't a good idea. You should just use an `enum Voiced { Dog(Dog), Duck(Duck) }` instead.

## The problem

If you view the full compiler diagnostics, you will see the following:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `HasVoice` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/lib.rs:39:36
   |
39 |     let mut quack_set: HashSet<Box<dyn HasVoice>> = HashSet::new();
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `HasVoice` cannot be made into an object
   |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
  --> src/lib.rs:4:17
   |
4  | trait HasVoice: PartialEq + Eq + Hash {
   |       --------  ^^^^^^^^^ ...because it uses `Self` as a type parameter
   |       |
   |       this trait cannot be made into an object...
```

You can see there's a problem with `PartialEq`. But what is it?

### What's the big deal with `PartialEq`?

The problem is that `PartialEq` is declared as `PartialEq<Rhs = Self>`, which defaults to the trait `PartialEq<Self>` if you don't specify a type parameter. In other words, PartialEq by default provides the comparison of a type with itself.
Consider the following code:

```rust
let duck: &dyn HasVoice = &Duck { /* ... */ };
let dog: &dyn HasVoice = &Dog { /* ... */ };
println!("{}", dog == duck);
```

What do you expect the outcome to be?

Well, `dog == duck` is equivalent to [`dog.eq(duck)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html), right? So Rust will look up the vtable for `dog`, see that `dog` does in fact have an `eq` method of type `fn eq(&self, rhs: Dog)`, and... wait a second. The `rhs` is explicitly *not* a `Dog`, it's a `&dyn HasVoice`, which contains a pointer to the type `Duck`. So there's absolutely no way you can call `eq` on these two types.

This issue was discovered [back in 2015](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22040), and the decided solution was [to ban any `Self` parameters in supertraits that aren't `&self`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/22452). This means that `PartialEq<Self>` *cannot* be used to compare two `Box<dyn HasVoice>` types.

So then what?

## How do I fix this?

Before we know how to fix the issue, we need to know first:

### How do we compare `Dog` and `Duck`?

Do they compare unequal always? Equal always? Something more exotic? The compiler doesn't know, only you do, so you should specify it. What should the answer be?

Let's say that `Dog`s and `Duck`s are always *unequal*. This is probably what most people expect from dogs and ducks in real life. How do we achieve that?

Well, you can do a bunch of trait machinery manually, but the easiest way is to use the [`dyn_partial_eq`](https://crates.io/crates/dyn_partial_eq/) crate.

Here's how:

```rust
use dyn_partial_eq::*;

#[dyn_partial_eq]
trait HasVoice {
    fn talk(&self);
}

#[derive(DynPartialEq, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Duck {
    name: String,
}

#[derive(DynPartialEq, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Dog {
    breed: String,
}
```

Then PartialEq works properly, right? So all is good?

Well, no. We forgot about `Hash`.

### How do we implement `Hash`?

The `Hash` trait is not object-safe. If you add it to the trait requirements, you'll just get a compile error. This is because [`Hash::hash`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html#tymethod.hash) is a generic function, so it can't be put in a vtable.

We can get around this by making a `DynHash` trait that isn't generic and instead takes a `&mut dyn` reference. Here's how you might do it:

```rust
trait DynHash {
    fn dyn_hash(&self, state: &mut dyn Hasher);
}

impl<H: Hash + ?Sized> DynHash for H {
    fn dyn_hash(&self, mut state: &mut dyn Hasher) {
        self.hash(&mut state);
    }
}

#[dyn_partial_eq]
trait HasVoice: DynHash {
    fn talk(&self);
}

impl Hash for dyn HasVoice {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.dyn_hash(state)
    }
}

impl Eq for Box<dyn HasVoice> {} // required for HashSet
```

That's all you need.

### The final code

```rust
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::collections::HashSet;
use dyn_partial_eq::*;

trait DynHash {
    fn dyn_hash(&self, state: &mut dyn Hasher);
}

impl<H: Hash + ?Sized> DynHash for H {
    fn dyn_hash(&self, mut state: &mut dyn Hasher) {
        self.hash(&mut state);
    }
}

#[dyn_partial_eq]
trait HasVoice: DynHash {
    fn talk(&self);
}

impl Hash for Box<dyn HasVoice> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.dyn_hash(state)
    }
}

impl Eq for Box<dyn HasVoice> {}

#[derive(DynPartialEq, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Clone)]
struct Duck {
    name: String,
}

#[derive(DynPartialEq, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Clone)]
struct Dog {
    breed: String,
}

impl HasVoice for Duck {
    fn talk(&self) {
        println!("duck quack!")
    }
}

impl HasVoice for Dog {
    fn talk(&self) {
        println!("dog bark!")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let duck: Duck = Duck {
        name: "an animal".to_string(),
    };

    let dog: Dog = Dog {
        breed: "an animal".to_string(),
    };

    let dog2: Dog = Dog {
        breed: "an animal".to_string(),
    };

    let mut quack_set: HashSet<Box<dyn HasVoice>> = HashSet::new();

    quack_set.insert(Box::new(duck.clone()));
    quack_set.insert(Box::new(dog.clone()));
    quack_set.insert(Box::new(dog2));

    assert_eq!(quack_set.len(), 2);
}
```

So that's how you implement Java in Rust. :P

#### For future improvement: The problem with `DynHash`

If you actually test the hash function we implemented here, you will notice that it doesn't work that well. More specifically, `Dog { breed: "the same string".to_string() }` and `Duck { name: "the same string".to_string() }` hash to exactly the same value, because Hash only cares about the stored data, not the unique type. This isn't a problem in theory, but it is quite annoying, because we really should not get hash collisions between these two types that easily. There's probably a way to fix this with a proc macro, similar to `dyn_partial_eq`, but that's probably not worth doing here.

Comment: Wow, what an answer! Thank you for the effort!

Comment: "So that's how you implement Java in Rust. :P" 